# Promotions not translated on cart and checkout page?

Tags: 8, commerce, transliteration

I have commerce site in 2 languages: English (default) and German.

I enabled translation of promotions so when I go to promotions admin page ( /admin/commerce/promotions ) for each promotion there is also "Translate" operation. I can enter German translation for each and it's saved well.

Problem is that when I'm on cart page or later on checkout page (German pages) promotions are displayed in English only. Other content, including subtotal, total, shipping costs are translated well, but promotions are always on English?!?

I searched but couldn't find that anybody reported that issue before, so most likely I overlooked something (hopefully), but just can't find out what it is.

Any idea why promotion titles are not displayed in page language, but always in English (default language)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think you are right: It's an issue. This is a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in its issue queue to track issues in a single place, not here.

Comment: Ok, I opened the issue here: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3187803

Answer (score 1):

I found work-around for this issue. Inside the template that prints that section (`commerce-order-total-summary.html.twig`) there is a loop that prints adjustments:

```
{% for adjustment in totals.adjustments %}
    <div class="order-total-line order-total-line__adjustment order-total-line__adjustment--{{ adjustment.type|clean_class }}">
        <span class="order-total-line-label">{{ adjustment.label|t }} </span><span class="order-total-line-value">{{ adjustment.amount|commerce_price_format }}</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and where adjustment label is printed I added **t** twig filter, so now it can be translated on standard user interface translations page:

```
/admin/config/regional/translate
```

I know that it's not optimal solution, but it works, so I hope this can help someone until bug is fixed.

Comment: +1  and sounds a bit like this could be the patch to solve this issue.

Comment: It's more workaround since other adjustments work well without t filter. Content should already be passed translated to template. This way promotion translations are not used, but instead raw string translations are.